# Prove that every permutation matrix is a product of adjacent transpositions?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know an elementary matrix that differs from the identity matrix by interchanging a sequential pair of rows is called an adjacent transposition. Equivalently, an adjacent transposition is a matrix of the form I+Ej,j+1 +Ej+1,j −Ej,j −Ej+1,j+1 for some row index j.
But, how would one prove that every permutation matrix is a product of adjacent transpositions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than thinking in terms of permutation matricies, consider the symmetric group in terms of their cycle decomposition. Each element of the symmetric group can be expressed as a product of disjoint cycles.
\begin{eqnarray*}
(a_1 a_2 \cdots a_k) \cdots (\cdots)
\end{eqnarray*}
 Each of these cycles can be expressed as the product of transpositions
\begin{eqnarray*}
(a_1 a_2 \cdots a_k) =(a_1 a_k) (a_2 a_k) \cdots (a_{k-1} a_k).
\end{eqnarray*}
Each transposition can be expressed as the product of adjacent transpositiions
\begin{eqnarray*}
(i j) =(i, i+1) (i+1, i+2) \cdots (j-2, j-1)(j-1, j ) (j-2, j-1)\cdots (i+1, i+2) (i, i+1).
\end{eqnarray*}